# How to fix error in symbols error using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I'm using igraph to subset a graph and replot then recalculate my network statistics given the newly plotted graph.  My code to do so is:

```
#Individual Node Subnet
CTxCVNodes <- subset(ExUniqueNodes, subset = CVCH == 1)
CTxCVNodes <- data.matrix(CTxCVNodes[,-2])
CHTxSubNet <- induced.subgraph(graph = net, vids=CTxCVNodes)
plot(CHTxSubNet, edge.arrow.size=.4, vertex.cex = 2, vertex.label=NA)
CHTxSubNet <- get.edgelist(CHTxSubNet)

indegreeCTxCVall <- igraph::degree(CHTxSubNet, mode="in")
outdegreeCTxCVall <- igraph::degree(CHTxSubNet, mode="out")
totaldegreCTxCVall <- igraph::degree(CHTxSubNet)
inclosenessCTxCVall <- igraph::closeness(CHTxSubNet, mode='in')
outclosenessCTxCVall <- igraph::closeness (CHTxSubNet, mode='out')
totalclosenessCTxCVall <- igraph::closeness(CHTxSubNet)
betweennessCTxCVall <- igraph::betweenness(CHTxSubNet)
PageRankCTxCVall <- igraph::page.rank(CHTxSubNet, vids=V(CHTxSubNet), directed = TRUE, damping=0.85, weights = NULL, options=igraph.arpack.default)
AnalysisNetCTxCVall <- data.frame(indegreeCTxCVall, outdegreeCTxCVall, totaldegreCTxCVall, inclosenessCTxCVall, outclosenessCTxCVall, totalclosenessCTxCVall, betweennessCTxCVall, PageRankCTxCVall$vector)
```

and it ran, until I got this error code:

```
Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  : 
  invalid symbol coordinates
Calls: plot -> plot.igraph -> <Anonymous> -> symbols
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Bit I'm having trouble deciphering what this error code means or how to fix it.